# Throwing custom error in knex transaction cause api to crash

Tags: node.js, transactions, knex.js

I am currently working on api with knex. I have to perform some operations in one big transaction and have to valdiate there also - if any validation returns "false" - transaction must be stoped. Problem is, whenever I toss "my" error there, even though all "Catch"es gets it and res is sended corrently- right after that my whole api crash with error:

> Cannot read property "removeListener" of null

which is strange, becouse there are no similar issues with catching errors caused by knex itself.

Strangley, if i would remove throwing of my errors - i will still get unhandled exception

> Cannot read property "rollback" of null

in code it looks like this:

```
f1(){
// (...)
     let noErrors = true;
    return global.knex
        .transaction((trx) => {
             return operation1(trx) //Knex operation returning object with parameter "correct"
             .then((output)=>{
                 if(output.correct === false)
                       throw new Error('CustomError');
             })
             .then(()=>{ return operation2(trx); })
             .then(()=>{ return operation3(trx); })
             // (...)
             .then(trx.commit)
             .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('TRANS. FAILED');
                    noErrors = false;
                    trx.rollback();
                    throw error; // Both with and without it - failed
              });
        })
        .then(() => {
               console.log('TRANS. OK');
        })
        .then(() => {
            if(noErrors)
                return {result:'MyResultsHere'};
            else
                return {result:'ErrorOccured'};
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return {result:'ErrorOccuredAgain'};
        });
```

}

This function's result (promise) is then returned :

```
        f1().then((output)=>{ 
                  console.log(output.result); 
                  // (...) sending response for request here
            }
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).send();
            });
```

AFter some additiona ltesting - it appears liek i can throw my custom errors, but issue here is with rollback - and soemtiems i get one more error:

> TransactionError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not
>   the SentClientRequest state

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing 2 different transaction handling syntaxes (simple examples below):

```
knex.transaction(trx => {
  // returning promise automatically calls commit / rollback
  return operation(1);
})
.then(results => console.log("commit was called automatically", results))
.catch(err => console.log("rollback was called automatically", err))
```

and

```
knex.transaction(trx => {
  // NOT returning promise so you need to call commit / rollback explicitly
  operation(1).then(results => trx.commit(results))
    .catch(err => trx.rollback(err));
})
.then(results => console.log("stuff from transaction commit", results))
.catch(err => console.log("error passed to rollback", err))
```

You are probably trying to do this:

```
f1(){
  // (...)
  return global.knex
    .transaction(trx => {
      return operation1(trx)
        .then(output => {
          if(output.correct === false) {
            // if wrong results promise will reject with "CustomError"
            throw new Error('CustomError');
          }
        })
        .then(() => operation2(trx))
        .then(() => operation3(trx))
        // (...)
        ;
    })
    .then(resultsOfLastThen => {
      console.log('TRANS. OK', resultsOfLastOperation);
      return { result: 'MyResultsHere' };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return { result: 'ErrorOccured' };
    });
}
```